How to maintain area of leaflet map visible as visible container area changes?
I have a leaflet map I am displaying. At some point I know the latlngbounds of the visible area of the map in the map container.
If the user resizes the container I want to pan/zoom so that that area of the map that is visible to stays the same (with the maximum zoom that achieves that).
I know I can keep track of the visible map bounds with map.on('moveend zoomend', myFn) (calling (map.getBounds()), and I'm less sure how to listen for the map container resizing, though I can get the container with map.getContainer().
In addition, I have two dialogs that when they open they cover a part of the map, and when that dialog toggles on/off I'd like to do the same thing, changing the pan/zoom so that the map area visible in the changing real estate stays visible at max zoom.
So I need to find the biggest pixel rectangle thats visible depending on the hidden state of the two dialogs, and then somehow set the map so that that pixel rectangle shows the desired map bounds, and I really don't know how to approach this.
I found one plugin that uses map.panBy() to move the map by a delta as a specific dialog opens/closes, which is interesting, but doesn't solve my issue.
The map I'm working on is this one:
https://supragamescommunity.github.io/maps/
so the layer's dialog in the top right corner expanding/shrinking would be an example.
But I'm working on adding left and right sidebar dialogs more like this:
https://joric.github.io/supraland/3d/
Any pointers greatly appreciated.

See this example. Click on the ball and see how the map moves popup-in-a-fixed-position

Very interesting set of examples, thanks. The resizing, however, doesn't show the scenario I want. I'm aiming for the part of the map visible as the window resizes to stay constant, which requires that as the container shrinks the map has to zoom out, and as it grows the map would zoom in.

@Grzegorz T. Regarding the examples - I was looking at example 56 - where do you source the SVG icons? For email and the like?

I mostly get icons from https://icomoon.io/
As for zoom in or zoom out of the map, this is a small sample of how it can be handled. Of course, it doesn't work perfectly, but it can be useful for the beginning of work.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Leaflet Map Resize Example with Zoom</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            resize: both;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Inicjalizacja mapy
        var map = L.map('map').setView([52.22977, 21.01178], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        function resizeMap() {
            map.invalidateSize();

            const container = document.getElementById('container');
            const width = container.offsetWidth;
            const height = container.offsetHeight;

            const newZoom = Math.min(Math.max(1, Math.floor(width / 100)), 18); 
            map.setZoom(newZoom);
        }

       
        const container = document.getElementById('container');
        const observer = new ResizeObserver(function(entries) {
            for (let entry of entries) {
                resizeMap();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(container);
    </script>
</body>
</html>



